# Ubuntu 15.10 boot very slow (cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored) Solution

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount

I had this problem, ubuntu was starting very slowly and the log was showing a timelaps quite long with this line :

> cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will
>   be ignored

I looked on internet for the solution and didn't really find it ! Except the fact to check the fstab and verify the UID of the drive. (I did a wrong manipulation before by removing the swap and reput it, ...)

But even by checking the UUID (the one for the swap was wrong so I changed it) Ubuntu was still starting slowly with the same message.

The solution I found (I don't know why it works with it and not the UUID) :

> Instead of the UUID of the partitions, put the path for them. Ex :
>   replace UUID=3fc32832-..... by /dev/sda1 (the root partition)

I did this for all of my partitions, restarted my laptop and it started as fast as before (arround 10 sec).

Hope I will help with that.

Cheers !!

Laurent

Comment: I do not know why this works,and I feel like there might be something wrong with this approach, but thank you so much.

Comment: I know this is not the best probably but in the meantime someone find a better solution hope it will work !!

Comment: What exactly did you change in which path?